# Android studio not generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

recently I updated my working android studio IDE into Android Studio 1.5.1. but now I'm facing some trouble as after updating it did not generating signed apk file. but when I plug a device and run the app, it runs properly. when I use

> Build -> Generate Signed Apk

in the Event Log it shows

```
10:38:51 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]
```

and the slider shows some time and it disappear. It does not show build generation completion dialog too. then I change build variant and try to run the app using a connected device. and in the Event Log it sows

```
10:43:32 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
```

after few seconds a pop up coms saying Apk(s) generated successfully, but still the signed apk is not there at the relavent folder. and the app runs in the device properly. and my full Event Log is as follow.

```
10:38:51 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]
10:43:32 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
10:43:46 AM Gradle build finished in 13s 964ms
10:43:46 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:46 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:46 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:46 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:47 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:47 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:47 AM Generate Signed APK
            APK(s) generated successfully.
            Reveal in Finder
10:43:52 AM Session 'app': Launched on samsung-sm_t211-4100cede9628b000
```

also my build.gradel file is as following.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lf"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 63
        versionName '2.0.9'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile project(':holoColorPickermaster')
    compile project(':qRCodeReaderViewlib')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':library')
}
```

so how can I fix this. I fully update Android studio after this was happen and it still the same.

Comment: clean and build then try

Comment: did it. but still the same.

Comment: you are getting any errors ?

Comment: What is the build variant selected?

Comment: no. there are no errors. I can run the app using a device with no problem. but still can't generate a signed apk as I mention in my question.

Comment: You need to have `.jks` key file in appropriate path.

Comment: I selected "release" as the build variant in trying to generate the signed apk. and when running the app I selected "debug" as build variant.

Comment: @Madhukar Hebbar , I have key files and I've generated signed apks before for the app. this happened few days ago as I update the android studio. before then the IDE worked properly

Comment: Have you checked all folders? Android Studio tends to change file organization after updates, maybe the build folder is in another directory, try using a `find` command for any *.apk file.

Comment: @  TomTsagk, when I'm generating the signed apk, it prompt me to specify the path so as the apk creates. I look for it in my directory. but it was not there.

Comment: @SamanthaWithanage Did you find a solution?

Comment: I just upgraded Android Studio and this is happening to me.  Adding lintOptions checkReleaseBuilds false is not helping.

Comment: It beggars belief that probably the most needed functionalilty of Android Studio just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by **completely removing** Android studio and it's related files and re install it. and now its working perfectly. it may be some issue with the plugins I'm using with the IDE. So in my **mac** I used following **terminal commands** to remove android studio

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
rm -Rf ~/.android
```

then I re install the **IDE** and install necessary **SDK**s. this fixed issue for me.

Comment: This seems like an extreme solution that would take a lot of time.  There must be a better way.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing same issue but i resolved the issue by adding below code in **build.gradle**

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

This issue would occur, Sometimes our application not follow all the rules and regulation according to Lint Tool

> Note: Add this in application module inside `android`

Comment: This did not help me. The upgrade to Android Studio 3.0.1 broke something.

Answer (score 9):

For Android Studio 3, instead of putting the APK directly into the folder, it creates a "release" folder or a folder that matches the flavor of your build.

So when you click `locate`, it puts you at the `app` level.  You need to go into the `release` folder to get your `APK` file.

[image: prompt to locate your APK file]

Typically you'd look in the `release` folder:

[image: folder structure in AS 3]

But if you built some other flavor aside from the `release` flavor, you would look for a folder with that name.

Comment: Oh gosh I feel stupid now, my eyes scanned for a .jpk file and not a folder with my apps name x) Thanks!

Comment: @Dale that really helped, thanks! I faced the same problem in Android Studio 3.0

Comment: To add to this - it's not necessarily the "release" folder, its named the same as the flavor you selected to generate apk.

Comment: Is there any way to block creating the "release" folder ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure that your keystore is correct, with the correct passwords and
   paths.
2. Then clean and rebuild.
3. Assemble (NOT EXECUTE OR RUN) the required build
4. Then 'Generate signed APK'

Comment: did, but no effect. most probably some problem with updating the IDE.

Comment: This did not help me.  The upgrade to 3.0.1 broke something.