# Unable to generate Signed APK using Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am stuck on issue of Generating Signed APK.

Steps I do:

1] I generate signed apk through menu Build -> Generated Signed apk
2] Android Studio shows message/pop-up that

```
 "Generate Signed APK"

 "APK(s) generated successfully"

 "Reveal in Finder"
```

3] However, when I move that folder it doesn't show generated signed apk.

Referred link :
[Android studio not generate signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171275/android-studio-not-generate-signed-apk)

Tried many things but no luck. Also, raised issue ticket on Google forum.

Comment: make new project and just copy paste your all stuff. It hardly take few minutes.

Comment: But what is the exact issue?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure however I have faced this issue , I had entered the keystore password without proper camel casing , I was not getting error with the same message . verify your alias and password . Hopefully should solve the issue.

Comment: I don't think so that their is a problem with Keystore