# Failed Generate Signed Bundle / APK

Tags: android, android-studio

An android project, which was initially published in google playstore needed few updates. After the changes, the Generate Signed Bundle / APK is not generating any file. It does not give any message or warning in the event log.

It generates unsigned release files when using Build > Generate APK. That file is rejected by google play store with the following message.

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures
```

I have also read the questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857240/failed-to-generate-signed-apk) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995051/generated-signed-bundle-apk-doesnt-work), but this is different.

Comment: did you mark the checkbox in Signature Version before release? Also it is better to upload you AAB to google play rather than just you APK

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171275/android-studio-not-generate-signed-apk

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just check whether you are checking the Signature checkbox before you generate a signed apk.

Answer (score 1):

*When you are going into Generate signed bundle/APK, make sure to check two boxes that are about signing APK.*

**Those two checkboxes are at the last step of making the APK, right before you click on Finish.**

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that you cannot upload an `unsigned apk` to play store. You need to create a `signed build apk` and then you will be able to upload your apk to playstore.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload **signed APK** to playstore

*Steps for creating signed APK*

```
1. Go to *build* menu
2. Click to *Generate signed Bundle or APK*
3. Select last option *APK*
4. Press next
5. Fill the fields
   a) Key Store path -> Create new or Choose existing for .jks file (Keep it safe).
   b) Key Store password -> any password. 
   c) key alias -> any name (better keep App name).
   d) key password -> any password (Keep Key store password and key password same).

6. Click Next

7. Select ***release*** in *Build Variants*.

8. Signature Versions -> ***Check V1***(Jar Signature) ***Check V2***(Full APK Signature)

9. Finish 


And upload that signed .apk to playstore.
```